# Connect to webSocket from java application

Tags: java, node.js, websocket

I try to connect from java SE application to webSocket running on a nodeJS server. I use this https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket library, but I have a problem. I can connect and send message from server to client but I can't from client to server.
Here is code that I use:

NODEJS

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: http })


wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

JAVA

```
try {
        WebSocketClient mWs = new WebSocketClient( new URI( "ws://localhost:8080" ), new Draft_10() )
        {
            @Override
            public void onMessage( String message ) {
                //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
                //String channel = obj.getString("channel");
                System.out.println(message);
            }


            @Override
            public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
                System.out.println( "closed connection" );
            }

            @Override
            public void onError( Exception ex ) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake sh) {
                System.out.println( "opened connection" );
            }

        };
        mWs.connect();
        String dog = "dog";
        mWs.send(dog);
        mWs.close();
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(okno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

After method send() nothing happen.